# Can frame made of 2x2's be used to hold drywall for a faux wall

Tags: drywall, framing

I'm looking to create a 5.5'(tall) x 12' (wide) faux-wall which will stand and rest on the floor and on and in front of an existing wall.  It's not supporting any weight other than the DW laid horizontally.  It just needs to look like a wall.
I want to keep the weight as light as possible
Can I use 2x2s for the frame to hold 1/2" UltraLight Dry wall(approx 80 lb)  instead of 2x4s?

It's 5 1/2' tall - so it's a 1 1/2 x 12 laid horizontally and 4x12 laid horizontally on top of that. The frame would of course coincide with the seam so the DW will be screwed in to the wood at at the seam and all along the border of the "wall".  Each piece can of course stand on its own.  However since they'll be screwed into the wood, it's the wood that is supporting their weight.

Furniture sliders would be on the bottom of the wood to allow this wall to slide back and forth when needed.  It'll probably slide back and forth 1x/week.  There will be a "U" bracket in the real wall holding the faux wall from falling over.

So the frame needs to hold the DW as it slides back and forth, with the U-brackets to hold it from falling over when standing.

Comment: please provide sketch or pictures to provide context of where other walls are, and how/where you plan to anchor it or otherwise support it (cabinets, sill etc...) There are stiffness & stability requirements you have to meet, even if it can hold the weight.

Comment: Yes, but the 2x2s will need support from falling over.

Comment: Your question is a little too lacking in context.  Yes, a piece of drywall can be nailed to some 2x2 and left standing on the floor.   For that matter, a piece of drywall can be supported by feet made out of cardboard or you can just lean a piece of drywall on anything with no special support or attachment.  The way you've written your question it would seem the only requirement is that the drywall itself should not fall down.  But surely that's not all?  Will the be in a room, in a building, with people in it?  Will it be very temporary (4 hours) or not so temporary (a year or more)?

Comment: Add added the info in the OP.  In short a U-Bracket groove keeps it from tipping, and the frame holds it while sliding.

Comment: I think it is fine, but as a sliding wall, you need to close both surfaces to stiffen the frame, which I think the studs should be closely spaced in nearing the square grid pattern.

Comment: Why drywall panels? Plywood or particle boards would not need the frame. But if you must, and like the drywall finish, you can instead back the entire drywall with a sheet of plywood or particle board (glued and/or screwed) for the stiffness otherwise provided by the 2x2s. For a moveable frame, I think the 2x2 frame will not be enough to prevent the drywall from bending and eventually crumbling in places from fatigue.

Comment: @P2000 - I would love to not have to sand DW,b ut I need to paint it to match the exact color of the "real" walls.  And since the size is 5.5' tall x 12' wide - I don't think they sell plywood or particle board that size.  So if I need to use 2 sheets - I thought DW is the only way to hide the seams and paint.

Comment: There's got to be a better way to disguise the entrance to your bat-cave!

Comment: @chaim, ok and so how about 2 sheets of plywood butted plus the 1/2in drywall all glued? You can press it until it dries. Use construction glue. Also, filling and sanding just screw heads is really easy. Use top coat or spackle, in two applications and light sanding.

Comment: @P2000 - gotcha, II misunderstood you - I thought you meant to use plywood in place of the DW.  I now understand that you were saying to use the plywood in place of the wood frame.  It would add a little weight 45lb vs 62 lb compared with 2x4.  Is it necessary if I went with 2x4's (instead of 2x2)?

Comment: @Chaim in that case I think not only is the stiffness of the wood itself important, but rigidity at the joints (corners) is what will make the *whole* assembly stiff. You could make it work with 2x3 and will need to brace the corners and the T's (where cross bars meet edge bars) with diagonal support or metal brackets and some wood glue. I think some experimentation is in order, so whatever you do, perhaps you need a continually "upgradeable" approach until it's stiff but not heavy. And you realize you have to tape the 1.5ft strip to the 4ft strip, requiring sanding?

Comment: Thanks everyone for all of the help.